# Conjugating a root subgroup by a Weyl group element

Tags: algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, weyl-group

Fix a field $k$. This is perhaps unnecessary, but assume $\operatorname{char} k = 0$.

Let $G$ be a reductive isotropic quasi-split algebraic $k$-group. Let $S \subset G$ be a maximal split torus (of rank $\ge 1$ as $G$ is isotropic). Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the Lie algebra, $\Phi_k$ be the relative root system of $G$ with respect to $S$, and for $\alpha \in \Phi_k$, let $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$ be the associated root space.
$$
\mathfrak{g}_\alpha(k) = \{ X \in \mathfrak{g}(k) : \operatorname{Ad}(s) X = sXs^{-1} = \alpha(s) X, \forall s \in S(k) \}
$$
For a root $\alpha$, let $U^{\alpha} = \exp \mathfrak{g}_\alpha$ be the associated root subgroup, and let $W = N(S)/T(S)$ be the Weyl group of $G$. All of this I mostly understand.

My first problem is: I know that $W$ is isomorphic to the Weyl group of $\Phi_k$, but I don't know exactly how this isomorphism is expressed, and I cannot find a concise description of this identification anywhere.

My second problem is with the following claim: Let $\overline{w} \in W$, and choose a representative $w \in N(S)$, and let $x \in U^{\alpha}$. Then
$$
wxw^{-1} \in U^{w(\alpha)}
$$
(Technically $w$ is in the $k$-points of $N(S)$ and $x$ is in the $k$-points of $U^\alpha$, but this is not important right now.) This claim arises in remark 1.6 of Deodhar's thesis *On central extensions of rational points of algebraic groups*.

I don't understand why this claim is true. I suspect this is mostly due to my lack of understanding of exactly how $N(S)/Z(S)$ is identified with the Weyl group of the root system $\Phi_k$.

Additionally, it should be possible to say more about $wxw^{-1}$ than just that it lands in $U^{w(\alpha)}$. For example, in the split case $G = \operatorname{SL}_n$ Milnor gives explicit descriptions of such conjugations in corollary 9.4 of *Introduction to Algebraic K-Theory*. Is there any source which has more general versions of these relations for quasi-split groups of types other than $A_n$? Perhaps some of this is in Deodhar's thesis, but I have not yet found it.

Comment: Your first question is a bit subtle. It's explained on page 110-111 of Brian's notes here: https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/files/course-material/OMN-201701-110663-1-Course_notes-v5.pdf. The proof that this is an equality is then Theorem 11.4.6 of those same notes. Your second problem can be checked directly by the definition of the root group (e.g. see Prop V.3.1 of these same notes).

Comment: I do not see how Prop V.3.1 addresses my question of what happens when you conjugate a root subgroup by a Weyl group element. The proposition describes the action of the torus $S$ on a root group, but not an action of the Weyl group.

Comment: Have you tried thinking about checking that $wxw^{-1}$ is in $U^{w(\alpha)}$ by checking that it normalizes $S$ and...